# Detecting a particular string value from a file, Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to detect a particular string value in an external txt file. In this case, I am trying to detect %%.

```
public void read(){
    while(x.hasNext()){
        String a = x.next();
        System.out.println(a);
        if(a == "%%"){
            System.out.println("Found the end");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("No end");
        }

    }
}
```

It is reading x correctly because it prints out the words from the file, but it says "No end" after every word, even the "%%". I'm sure I am making some dumb mistake somewhere, I just can't find it. x looks like this: apple orange %% grapes. Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: Use .equals() for string comparison

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
    if(a.trim().equals("%%"))
    {
        System.out.println("Found the end");
    }
```

That should get rid of any excess whitespace at the end of the string as well as ensure a good comparison!

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `String::equals()` for comparison but not the operator `==`. The `==` operator compares the address location of String and the string literal `%%` in your case.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `==` would work just fine. Try running this: `System.out.println("hi" == "hi");`

Comment: With your edit, I changed my example... `String s1 = "hi"; String s2 = "hi"; System.out.println(s1 == s2);` Still `==` works fine.

Comment: That's because both the string literals (i.e., hi )address location is same.

Comment: @kentcdodds A simple test would be keep the break point at the println statement. And see the address of s1, s2 in the debugger. That should give you idea.

Comment: That makes sense, but why is it printing `true` (I believe you, I'm just trying to figure out what's happening).

Comment: @kentcdodds As I said, in your snippet, the `==` compares the address location. String literals are in general stored in read only location ( I believe Java does same as C++ in this point ). So, in either case you are referring to same address location and hence getting true.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13467/discussion-between-kentcdodds-and-mahesh)

Answer (score 1):

You should use logical eqality using `equals` method rather than `==`which check for reference .

```
if(a.equals("%%")){
        System.out.println("Found the end");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("No end");
    }
```